# How to Choose Accepted Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

If you are not logged in, you can still post anonymously.
The same goes with users who have deleted their account.
The questions asked by that user that no longer exists can not chose an accepted answer if the user has not already chosen one.
How can we solve this problem?
I suggest that mods can also review "forgotten questions without accepted answers".

Comment: Is requirement for questions to have accepted answers though? My understanding is that the asker accepts the one that works best for them,  but that doesn't necessarily make it the best or even most correct answer. What are the implications if a question never gets "officially" answered other than it always shows up in the unanswered filter? I'm not saying I'm opposed. I'm just trying to understand the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like what Sven Yargs had to say in his answer to [this related ELU question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6554):

> *The questions I ask tend to be difficult to answer in a way that clearly and fully disposes of the question .. Accepting an answer means saying that the matter is settled, and often I think it isn't*.

In other words, not every question needs to have an answer accepted, particularly if the matter was never completely and exhaustively settled.

As for the case where users have deleted their accounts with questions that still have no accepted answer, only the original poster knows for sure which answer was most helpful, if any. (Perhaps none of them were, and that's why the account was deleted?)

I think it's best to let the system stand as-is. Folks can always upvote what they feel are excellent answers to the question.