# What if I cannot choose the best answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

What do I do if my question received a few very good answers and each of them is useful? I have had it this way a few times and some of my questions are still left without the best answer chosen.

Incidentally, is it frowned upon if the OP doesn't choose the best answer?

Comment: This discussion is relevant: [As a learner, how do I choose which answer to accept?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3421/). Also the [What does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) topic in the help center. [How to Choose Accepted Answers](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1346/) is also related. The summary of the related links is that you don't have to choose the objectively best answer. You should choose the answer that worked best for you personally.